# How to load images of array of objects in order?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array that looks something like this:

```
$scope.myArray = [
    {name:   'some name',
     age:    '20',
     imgURL: 'some/url.png'
    },
    {name:   'another name',
     age:    '53',
     imgURL: 'some/url2.png'
    }
]
```

The array has about 500 objects in it, and all of the objects are being loaded onto the page in an ng-repeat that looks something like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="person in myArray">
    <img ng-src="{{person.imgURL}}"/>
</div>
```

Now, if the user is on a desktop with a good wireless connection, the relatively small images load pretty quickly on the page.  But the last time I tried on my phone...it was pretty rough because the screen only has space for about 6 images, and they don't have any particular order in which they are loaded onto the page.  As a result, the user is left staring at a black screen until they scroll down, or until the images at the top load.

I've been trying to figure out a good way to **force these images to load in order** by using promises but haven't had any luck yet.  Does anyone have any ideas of how I might be able to do this?  Thanks!

For those of you who may be curious, the backend is simply a json file that is being load through an angular service that looks like the following:

```
  $scope.generatePeople = function(){
      getPeopleService.getPeople().then(function(response){
          $scope.myArray = response;
      }, function(error){
      });
  };

.service('getPeopleService', ['$http', '$q', '$rootScope', function($http, $q, $rootScope){
    var getPeople = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get('people.json').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
            deferred.reject(status);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    return({
        getPeople: getPeople
    })
}])
```

Comment: Your question is very broad. First of all no one knows what kind of back end you are using. Second of all your question has several problems that need to be solved not a focused topic.

Comment: You may try to make a series of `Promise.race(arr)` s with splicing out the loaded image from the `arr` in the next turn.

Comment: Hey @Ohjay44, thanks for the help.  I just addressed your backend issue and edited the original post. What else is broad to you?  I'm happy to give more details, but it is a relatively plain issue that I simply don't know how to solve.  Open to any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: How about lazy loading your images? Only loading the first 6 (or so) visible images in your mobile scenario seems better than loading all 500 in a specific order. There are Angular lazy loading examples out there to experiment with.

Comment: Are the images stored on a server or are these static images from a URL?  There are certain things you can look into like angular image loading.

Comment: @Ian Gilroy, that could work.  Would I be able to change how many load depending on the size of the screen?

Comment: @Ohjay44  The images are stored in a local directory of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish this is to convert those images to base64 and then send them as one json response. This is not a problem with your code but with the way browser load images. Another way also is to request each image through ajax and request another image after the other finishes

Another way if you don't want your users to stare at a blank screen is to have a spinner in a element behind the image and as the image loades the spinner is covered.

Comment: *"The only way"* ... please don't be so absolute since there are numerous alternatives. Loading all that base64 data has major implications on payload for the data also

Comment: Yes their are other ways(ive dont it but not worth it) but last i checked browsers don't fire events for images done loading via url so he would not know when they are done loading.

Comment: well that's not accurate either because you can certainly create image load listeners. Image elements do have onload events

Comment: @charlietfl i am aware but that is none standard and unreliable.

Comment: not unreliable at all ... have never heard of an image `onload` not triggering correctly and `onerrror` works fine when mime or path or status fails

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you may choose to create a series of `Promise.race`s as follows;

```js
function racer(proms){
  Promise.race(proms)
         .then(val => { var idx = images.indexOf(val);
                        console.log(val);   // doSomething(val);
                        proms.splice(idx,1);
                        images.splice(idx,1);
                        proms.length && racer(proms);
                      });
}

var images = [...Array(10)].map((_,i) => ({imageNo : i, loadTime: ~~(Math.random()*9001)+1000})),
  promises = images.map(img => new Promise((resolve,reject) => setTimeout(_ => resolve(img),img.loadTime)));
    
racer(promises);
```

In this model example we have an image object which randomly loads in 1-10 seconds. So we generate an array of 10 of these images and map it into a `promises` array. After every race we splice out the winner both from `promises` and `images` array and start a new race.

Now that you are fed with images in the order of fastest to slowest all you have to do is to insert them into your page from the top to bottom as you receive them.